# SQL Server not geting rows from OraOLEDB linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, oledb, linked-server

I have two Windows 2008 Server 64x machines. One running Oracle 10.2.x.x.x  (Express Edition) and other SQL Server 2008 R2 with [ODAC 12c (12.1.0.2.4)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).

I had created linked server, tested connection and it passes. I can see all Oracle tables, but when I query them, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORACLE..USER.PERSON
```

All I get back are columns without no rows. If I run query from Oracle SQL Developer I get around 13000 rows.

What could be problem? I thought it was problem with backward compatibility, but according to this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/install121024-2704210.html) it is not. It could be something with permissions/security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was nothing to do with linked server configuration. I didn't know that after every insert I need to commit changes.

```
SQL> commit;
```